# Regex filtering Japanese

Tags: php, regex, unicode, cjk

I want to allow A-Z, a-z, and Japanese kanji, hiragana, and katakana and nothing else.
So far I've come up with this:

```
$pattern = '/[^\w\x{3041}-\x{3094}\x{30A1}-\x{30fA}\x{30fC}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}_\-]+/u';
preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

I'm not sure if this form of regex is PHP specific. I'm accepting a string in the URL and want to filter out quotes and other "dangerous" characters. The odd thing about the above "pattern" is that with or without "d", digits are not matched.

So the following does the same thing:

```
$pattern = '/[^\d\w\x{3041}-\x{3094}\x{30A1}-\x{30fA}\x{30fC}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}_\-]+/u';
```

I'm interested in any improvements or corrections - not being a regex wizard myself.

Comment: It could be easier to blacklist the dangerous characters and search for them instead.

Comment: I have no idea what characters could be dangerous. Any info on this? I am using this string in a MySQL where clause. So it really needs to be 100% sanitized.

Comment: is it possible for you to use prepared (e.g. [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php)) instead?  That will generally be safer.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, I'm using ZF's db and select classes which apparently use prepared statements. Do you know if this is the case?

Comment: Yes, [Zend_Db_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html) is a prepared statement class.

Comment: casperOne, there is a reason why there is a new paragraph. You are from NY. You should know English. This question is not about CJK, it's about JAPANESE (yelling intentional). Of course continue to mislead others since you too know so much about the subject. In case it's not obvious, I do want to filter only certain JAPANESE characters. Nothing to do with CJK. However, if you want to reward people for making pointless edits, by all means do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` includes digits; it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  So either way you're allowing them.

Comment: So "d" is only [0-9], and "w" is [A-Za-z0-9_]?

Comment: @sims, that's correct.  You may find this [character class list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) helpful.

Comment: I was using http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html Obviously it's not clear. Thanks for this clarification!

Comment: @sims, that site in general is quite good; [this table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class), on another page, explains the POSIX character classes.

Comment: So can I assume that the above regex combined with the ZF classes should be quite safe?

Comment: @sims, I'm still not clear why you have to filter manually at all.  Generally, prepared statements should be enough.  However, we would have to see your SQL calls to be sure.  Also, I haven't checked your Unicode ranges.

Comment: Perhaps it is enough, and thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I must be paranoid reading about all the various attacks. Basically, the parts of the URL refer to records in the db. They can be a mixture of roman, hiragana, katakana, and kanji. The SQL is as simple as "select * from table where alias = string". Taking my project seriously, I don't want something or someone malicious to enter something in the URL that may compromise the DB or other parts of the server.

Comment: @sims, if you use the `query` method from [`Zend_Db_Statement`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html), and use a ? placeholder for the user input (string) like the example, I believe that's enough.

Comment: For the record, \w, when the modifier u is present, is equivalent to [_\p{N}\p{L}] (an underscore or any Unicode letter or any Unicode Number), according to PCRE documentation: "\w  any character that \p{L} or \p{N} matches, plus underscore". And \d, to \p{Nd} (any Unicode decimal digit).

Answer (score 3):

At Unicode,

x3040-x308f: Hiragana including a few old chars.
x30a1-x30ff: Katakana. including a few symbol.

However,x4e00-x9eff are assigned for CJK character set. Not Japanese.

CJK means China, Japan and Korea.

You can describe CJK char area by unicode. However you can not describe Japanese Kanji area by unicode. Because in CJK code area, Chinese Kanji and Japanese Kanji are mixed. Not completely separated. Chinese and Japanese Kanji share some chars. But most of chars are different due to each sides' own evolution.

See following site. It is quite heavy. And your computer should have enough fonts to read it.
http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks for the info on this. I was particularly concerned I was filtering the correct characters.